# Take mulitple pictures using image_picker in flutter

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I've got an app up and running in flutter using ImagePicker. At the moment, after the picture is taken and the check mark (for OK) selected, the ImagePicker closes and the app shows my screen to allow taking either another picture or selecting an image from the gallery.

What I would like to do is take a picture, and then after the 'ok', show the camera again, until the user x's out of the camera.

Do I override an event to change this behaviour, and if I do, which event?

Comment: Show the code whichever you have tried.

Comment: You might wanna use multi_image_picker instead: https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker